# SwfitUI Tab View Image padding when not selected

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My TabView is such:

```
               TabView {
                    Home().tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house")
                        Text("Home").padding(.top, 20)
                    }
                    Profile().tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle")
                        Text("Profile").padding(.top, 20)
                    }
                }
```

and when the View is not selected the identifier shows like this:

[image: TabView]

See Red Circle

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4. Which is your env?

Comment: Xcode 12, iOS 14

Comment: Just tested with Xcode 12b/iOS14 as well - works fine. Is this all code you have?

Comment: Pretty much, It's just in an if/else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
YourView()
   .tabItem {
      Image(systemName: "Home").font(.system(size: <enter-your-size-here>))
      Text("Home")
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide any explanation/comment why this works? And why there is a need to set font on an Image?